# NULL Claim Store JAVA DXA1.4

Tags: 2013, dxa, smarttarget, dxa-java, ambient-data-framework

I am getting Claimstore as Null in java. My claim store is null from the below code.:

```
 @SneakyThrows(ParseException.class)
    private ResultSet executeSmartTargetQuery(AbstractSmartTargetPageModel stPageModel, final TcmUri pageUri) throws SmartTargetException {
        TcmUri publicationUri = new TcmUri(TcmUtils.buildPublicationTcmUri(pageUri.getPublicationId()));

        ClaimStore claimStore = AmbientDataContext.getCurrentClaimStore();
        System.out.println("Claim Store "+ claimStore);
        String triggers = AmbientDataHelper.getTriggers(claimStore);
```

I got to know the filter mapping to be add, [ADF ClaimStore not available (null) in Java Application](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4176/adf-claimstore-not-available-null-in-java-application) After that I added the filter in below code, I am getting 404 Error:

```
public class WebAppConfiguration implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext servletAppContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        servletAppContext.register(DxaSpringInitialization.class);
        servletAppContext.register(CeairModuleInitializer.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(servletAppContext));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(servletAppContext));
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/");

        registerFilter(servletContext, AmbientClientFilter.class, "/*");
    }
```

MY dxa.property file is as follows :

```
#EHCache configuration
#cache expired elements for amount of seconds
cache.expired.ttl=120
cache.dependency.ttl=120
cache.ttl=1800

## DXA

# Web Properties
#dxa.web.views.prefix=/WEB-INF/Views/
#dxa.web.views.suffix=.jsp

# Possible profiles:
# search.aws - Activates AWS in Search, Not compatible with search.solr
# search.solr - Activates SOLR in Search, Not compatible with search.aws
# dxa.no-cache - Makes DXA use NoCacheProvider in Tridion
# test Activates - Testing context, Only affects unit testing. Activated in Tests by default. Doesnt affect application.
spring.profiles.active=search.solr,adf.context.provider 

# Multiple-line configuration is possible
#spring.profiles.active=search.solr, \
#  dxa.no-cache

#spring.profiles.include=

## Modules
# - All commented are optional

# Mapping for CID resolver (Filter or Servlet)
#dxa.modules.cid.mapping=/cid/*

# Class to use as a resolver for CID images
dxa.modules.cid.className=com.sdl.context.image.servlet.ImageTransformerServlet

# External path to the server which runs DXA for back-mapping for CID Service
#dxa.modules.cid.appHostMapping=localhost:8088

# Redirect link for XO GA client
#dxa.modules.xo.fallbackRedirectUrl=/redirect/
```

Do someone have any idea, how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely that the `AmbientClientFilter` is not enabled.

It should not be needed to do that in code like you tried; it should be done through DXA properties configuration. This config has changed quite a bit in earlier DXA versions (IIRC, for some versions you still needed a `web.xml`).

I would recommend to try with a newer DXA version. Preferably the latest (DXA 1.6 since you're on 2013 SP1), but if you try DXA 1.5, you can get away without changing the CM-side.